# Regarding matching index error

Tags: python, web2py

I am trying to write the API being called by front end
So the code dose reading data from DB and convert to Array.
if you see the second if statement I am trying to check city is in array.
If it's true adding code to previous code with OR.
It gets an error in second if statement.
Any solution for that.
Thank you.

```
import pyodbc
import json
import collections
location_info=[]
for row in\
    db().select(db.location_info.city,db.location_info.code,db.location_info.latitude,db.location_info.longitude):
   d = collections.OrderedDict()

   if len(row.code.split(" ")) == 2:
        row.code=row.code.split(" ")[0]
   if row.city in location_info["city"]:
        temp_location=location_info["code"]
        temp_location+=" OR "+row.code

        d["code"]=temo_location
        location_info.append(d)



   else:
        d["city"]=row.city
        d["code"]=row.code
        d["latidue"]=row.latitude
        d["longitude"]=row.longitude
        location_info.append(d)
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is probably an index error because there is no `"city"` in `location_info`.  It looks like `location_info` is a list of objects, each one being a dictionary with keys such as `city`.  What you probably want instead is to make `location_info` a dictionary where the keys are the city names and the values are what you were previously appending to the list.  First initialize it as a dictionary instead of a list:

```
location_info = {}
```

Then make the second "if" statement search the dictionary for that city:

```
if row.city in location_info:
```

Then when adding to `location_info`, assign to the dictionary rather than appending:

```
location_info[row.city] = d
```

Comment: I switched to    d['code']=row.code
            d['latidue']=row.latitude
            d['longitude']=row.longitude
            location_info[row.city] = d I am getting this error list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Possibly because `location_info` is a list?  Have you tried what I suggested, make `location_info` a dictionary instead?